# Linphone Android - Error trying make (Build of libvpx for x86 failed | vp8) - Mac OSX

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone, libvpx

I'm working on an application with SIP using Linphone.
I got the git repository from:

> git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive

I followed the Readme, and get the following error if i execute `make`:

> /Users/---/Development/AndroidSIPPI/linphone-android/submodules/externals/libvpx/vp8/encoder/onyx_if.c:
>   In function 'vp8_create_compressor':
>   /Users/---/Development/AndroidSIPPI/linphone-android/submodules/externals/libvpx/vp8/encoder/onyx_if.c:2059:45:
>   error: 'vp8_copy32xn' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   /Users/---/Development/AndroidSIPPI/linphone-android/submodules/externals/libvpx/vp8/encoder/onyx_if.c:2059:45:
>   note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
>   function it appears in
>       [CC] vp8/encoder/picklpf.c.o make[2]: *** [vp8/encoder/onyx_if.c.o] Error 1 make[2]:**  Waiting for unfinished
>   jobs.... make[1]:  **[.DEFAULT] Error 2 Build of libvpx for x86
>   failed. make: ***
>   [/Users/---/Development/AndroidSIPPI/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/libvpx/x86/libvpx.a]
>   Error 1

I want to import the Linphone-Library to my existing project. Can anybody help me or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

The PATH vars has to set right!

on MAC:

> sudo vi /etc/paths

and add

```
/Users/USERNAME/YOURPATH/android-ndk-r9b

/Users/USERNAME/YOURPATH/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk

/Users/USERNAME/YOURPATH/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools

/Users/USERNAME/YOURPATH/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
```

and also use PORT to install ALL package depencies